# Read environment variables from file in Windows Batch (cmd.exe)

Tags: java, windows, command-line, cmd, environment-variables

I'm trying to read variables from a batch file for later use in the batch script, which is a Java launcher. I'd ideally like to have the same format for the settings file on all platforms (Unix, Windows), and also be a valid Java Properties file. That is, it should look like this:

```
setting1=Value1
setting2=Value2
...
```

Is it possible to read such values like you would in a Unix shell script? The could should look something like this:

```
READ settingsfile.xy
java -Dsetting1=%setting1% ...
```

I know that this is probably possible with `SET setting1=Value1`, but I'd really rather have the same file format for the settings on all platforms.

To clarify: I need to do this in the command line/batch environment as I also need to set parameters that cannot be altered from within the JVM, like -Xmx or -classpath.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do this in a batch file as follows:

```
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('type Settings.txt') do SET %%i
java -Dsetting1=%setting1% ...
endlocal
```

This reads a text file containing strings like "SETTING1=VALUE1" and calls SET to set them as environment variables.

setlocal/endlocal are used to limit the scope of the environment variables to the execution of your batch file.

The CMD Command Processor is actually quite powerful, though with a rather byzantine syntax.

Comment: After a long time looking for a solution, I found this solution. Thank you!

Comment: How would you ignore a "comment" (for example, a line starting with a "#" character) - ?

Comment: @malthe - one way is just to ignore any error messages the comment lines produce, or hide them thus `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('type Settings.txt') do SET %%i 2> NUL:`

Comment: @malthe - Add _eol=<comment character>_. `FOR /F "tokens=* eol=#" %%i in ('type Settings.txt') do SET %%i`

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner also unquotes value before assigning it to a variable:

```
for /F "delims== tokens=1,* eol=#" %%i in (%filename%) do set %%i=%%~j
```

- `delims==` split lines by `=` character
- `tokens=1,*` put first token (name) into `%%i` and the rest (value) into `%%j`
- `eol=#` skip lines starting with `#` (comments)
- `%%~j` [remove surrounding quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-dequote.html) from value

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the property file as a parameter to a Java program (that may launch the main program later on). And then benefit from the multi platform paradigm.

Comment: Yes, that's generally true, but I need to configure stuff like -Xmx too, which of course cannot be changed once the JVM is running.

Comment: Oh I see, it's sounds overkill compare to the solutions but you may re-launch the Java from another Java. Don't get my wrong I do prefer the selected solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
FOR /F "eol=# tokens=*" %%i IN (%~dp0.env) DO SET %%i
```

> It will only work in .bat file (not cmd.exe)

##### This will do the following:

- Skips all lines that **start** with `#` (can be used for comments)
- Reads the file `.env` which sits in the same directory of the batch script and pass the lines to `SET`

To be more helpful This is the .env file i was parsing

```hs
# The name of the mariadb service to be installed
MariaDb_serviceName=Swoole_MariaDB
# which port the mariadb server will run at
# notice i added /A flag so that the SET command stores the variable as a number
MariaDb_port=1214
# password of mariadb root user
MariaDb_rootPassword=
# Database to be created after installing mariadb
MariaDb_createDataBase=data
# the server service name to be installed
Server_serviceName=Swoole_Server
```

Comment: No need for `/a`, as batch knows about only one variable type anyway: STRING. `set /a` is used to translate strings into integers to do arithmetic and assigns again a string to the variable.

Comment: @Stephan I have modified the answer, I did not know about it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It may be wise to only import specific variables from a properties file (ones you know about ahead of time), in that case I recommend a function like the following:

```
:parsePropertiesFile
    set PROPS_FILE=%1
    shift
    :propLoop
    if "%1"=="" goto:eof
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('type %PROPS_FILE% ^| findStr.exe "%1="') do SET %%i
    shift
    GOTO propLoop
goto:eof
```

Which would be called by `call:parsePropertiesFile props.properties setting1 setting2` to set the variables setting1 and setting2

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the OS' environment variables from within a Java program:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```